# How update JSON structure

Tags: jquery, json

I have a very complex JSON structure in my JSON file. The file has many records. If I want to add a field/property/array later what's the best way to do this? I'll have to add it to every record right?

To clarify more: Let's say later I need to add an additional array to my master JSON structure. Is there an easy way to do this? Or, if I have 100 records/objects in my JSON file do I have to MANUALLY add the new field/property/array? (Not speaking of doing it programmatically.)

For example, let's say this represents ONE record in my JSON file...

```
  "devices": [
    {
        "deviceName": "ABC 6 Plus",
        "deviceShortName": "ABC6plus",
        "productId": "223311",
        "dropdowns": [
            {
                "dropDownText": "models:",
                "dropDownItems": [ "ABC6 Plus", "ABC6s Plus" ]
            },
            {
                "dropDownText": "logo:",
                "dropDownItems": [ "Exposed Logo", "Covered Logo" ]
            }
        ],
        "imagewidth": "400",
        "skinPositions": [
            { "side":  "4422" },
            { "top":   "3322" },
            { "bottom":   "1122" }
        ],
        "invalidSkins": [
            "yellow"
        ]
    }
```

So, let's say I have a JSON file with 100 of these records. Now, I want to add "productName" key/value to the dataset. Do I have to manually add this to every record?

```
"productName": ""
```

Or is there an editor, etc... that I can do this quickly in? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First your question need more clarification.

Use your favorite programming language to grab all JSON records and loop on them add this field to each one then write them over what ever storage you use (DB, File, ..).

or you can handle this from another side by handling not found exception from retrieving side.
For example: while retrieving check if JSON record have this field if not don't deal with it.

Comment: If you using Sublime Text editor you can use it's search and replace regex feature by using in find: (\{\s.*"deviceName": .*?,) and in replace: $1\n"productName": "",

Comment: Just copy all JSON records in Sublime then use find and replace all

Answer (score 0):

I assume by records you mean an array of record.
Since you haven't mentioned any structure and the language you're using, take this for example :(javascript)

```
var a = {};
a.b = [];
a.b.c = {}; 
//a is populated
```

Now the structure of a is "a has property b which is an array of property c"
So, if you want to add another property "d" to "b"(array of b), you can use:
    forEach() function

For the example given,

```
a.b.forEach(function(record){
  record['d'] = 'new property' //or anything
})
```

Now, each record of "b" will have a property "d".

Comment: Thanks @Kandhan .... please see my clarified OP. I'm not necessarily looking to do this programmatically.

Comment: I guess you'll have to do it programmatically. Its few lines of code, just like I mentioned above.